# Automatically select video source from dialog? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, camera, dialog, usb, image-capture

I've been playing with a generic usb camera to take snapshots every few seconds. With the help of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298250/vb-net-and-webcam-select-video-source-dialog), I was able to get the camera working; however, when you click the button to connect to the camera, a dialog box appears.

The difference between the other question and my question is that I have two video sources: a built in webcam and a usb camera. I also intend to have multiple cameras connected, all taking pictures. It appears that when you have multiple devices, you always get the dialog box where you have to choose the device. I'm trying to automatically choose the camera (and eventually cameras, plural) without this dialog box.

There are other pieces of sample code that I have played with - samples that have a device listbox that is populated; I thought this was what I needed (and I'd just remove the listbox control and process the list and what to connect to in code), but every one of these samples populates the listbox with "Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32)" instead of the devices listed in the dialog after attempting to connect to this "device."

Surely there's a way to automate the webcam(s) I'm connecting to instead of having to choose it from a dropdown in a Windows dialog, right? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ultimately was to use [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to access the camera; this also allows for connecting to multiple cameras at the same time.